# Absolute Div over resized image : fit both in width and height

Tags: html, css, image, resize, absolute

Sorry if my explainations are unclear.

I want an image to fit/resize in both height and width to its parent, which is something "max-width:100%;max-height:100%;" easily does.

But : I have an absolute div over this image, and I would like it to cover exactly the image.

My code is:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color:green;
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#bg{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#absolute-div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    border:5px solid blue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/850x450" id="bg"/>
        <div id="absolute-div">
            Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
</div>
```

Or as a codepen: https://codepen.io/Eboww/pen/oNQYbmQ

Currently, the image does fit well, if I resize both horizontally and vertically.

But I would like the "absolute-div" to cover exactly the image.

If I add `width: max-content;` to .container, then this does the trick, but my image won't fit if I resize horizontally.

It's like whatever I try, either the resizing won't work in one way, or my absolute div won't cover my image.

What am I doing wrong?

(once again, sorry for the bad english)

Thank you!

(Also, it's a simplified version of my issue, so I can't, let's say, create a div and use my image as background)

Comment: Please don't link to external code... [edit] your question and use a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992).  Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added a snippet. (since it's a resize issue I thought it would be more convenient to put a codepen, but I forgot you could open a snippet in full screen, and also yes links can break, sorry about this)

Comment: is the ratio of the image known?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes the ratio of the image would be fix (same as example).